# How to calculate liquidity pool and initial liquidity?

Tags: sol, liquiditypool

I'm having trouble understanding the liquidity pool and initial liquidity calculation.

SOL Pool I've learned that there is a ratio at which you can solve SOL Pool if you have Liquidity Pool. So you can multiply liquidity pool by x and you will get sol pool.

(1) But I can't seem to solve how Liquidity Pool is calculated.

(2) Which brings me to my next question, how is initial liquidity calculated. When looking at the dexes I can see that deployers and putting in 10 sol, and then on the Solana liquidity pool bot and the dexes it'll show as 10 + 85% or 10 + 100%. I can't find any docs referring to this.

(3) Final question is also if a market cap were to be 1,000,000 with 1,000,000,000 supply and a deployer owned 10% of that. Let's say that the total SOL Pool was 250 and the chart had 100k liquidity in it.
If they sold their 10% in one shot would that be 25 SOL to their wallet or would it be 535 SOL (100K), or would it be something different because of price impact and liquidity in the chart?

Answer (score 0):

yo, if the the AMM you are using and referring to in your post is using the concentrated liquidity model from uniswap v3 you can read more and learn how it works here: https://uniswapv3book.com/milestone_0/uniswap-v3.html

Comment: let me check it out, thanks.